# Hash in dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile, environment-variables

I am trying to add ENV variables to a docker file. One of the ENV variables is a password and the password contains a hash (#) character. This is commenting out the rest of the password. How do I escape this in my docker file?

[image: Screenshot of a portion of the dockerfile with the # in my password]

Comment: I don't think that is commenting out the rest of the password, despite what your syntax highlighter is telling you. If you're having an actual problem, please show us enough of the Dockerfile to reproduce the behavior you're asking about.

Comment: Also, please don't post images of text: just post the text itself, formatted as a code sample. That makes it much easier for people to interact with the code/configuration you're asking about.